# Create a readonly pointer argument of any type in C

Tags: c, macros, const-pointer, readonly-variable

I want to make a macro that when given a type T, will return a pointer type that is readonly when passed to a function, like so:

```
void foo( readonly_ptr(char) str )
{
    // can only read from str, not modify it
}
```

This proved to be harder than I thought, since simply prepending `const` isn't enough.

My current code is:

```
#define readonly_ptr(T) \
const typeof(T)*
```

Which works for "simple" types.

But doesn't work with all types.

When given a pointer-to-array type (e.g. `int(*)[10]`) it turns it into `int(*const*)[10]` which still allows the function to modify the array like this:

```
void foo( readonly_ptr(int(*)[10]) arr )
{
    (**arr)[0] = 1;
}
```

Similarly for pointer types (e.g. `char*`) it turns it into `char *const*` which can have its underlying `char`s modified.

Is there a way to make a macro that guarantees a readonly parameter?

If not, is there another way to make sure a function won't modify the argument, without having to specify the exact type every single time.

I also tried always passing `const void*` every time I needed a readonly, however that is still legally cast-able to a modifiable type.

Comment: You could simply define separate macros for dealing with array types. Out of curiosity, _why_ do you need this? It's usually much clearer to specify the type explicitly, without wrapping it in macros that are unfamiliar to anyone but yourself.

Comment: @paddy this doesn't only fail with array types, it also fails with any pointer type (other than function pointer)

Comment: Why do you need the macro? Most C code doesn't use such a macro, and one reason is that (at best) it is tricky to write such a macro.

Comment: You cannot add `const` to the bottom-level type in a uniform way. Your macro doesn't exist

Comment: Such a macro does not exist and it is not needed. 

When you write the function definition, you decide which part of the indirection should be constant or not.

Comment: Do you want to transform `int(*)[10]` to `const int(* const *)[10]`?

Comment: With what you have, could you use `void foo( readonly_ptr(readonly_ptr(int[10])) arr)`?

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi sure, and the jist of what I'm saying is that you define separate macros for all those special kinds of cases. You still haven't addressed the _"why?"_ part of my comment, which was echoed by others in the comments. The reason for asking that is due to this question carrying the strong aroma of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/200806).

Comment: @tstanisl yes. I want the argument passed to be of a non-modifyable type

Comment: @IanAbbott yes that works, but with every level of indirection it's one more call to `readonly_ptr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if your underlying question is whether it is possible to make the memory location immutable in every case the answer is probably no. I don't think there is a way to make something 100% read-only when pointers are involved with a Makro like this.

- If not, is there another way to make sure a function won't modify the argument, without having to specify the exact type every single time?

This might differ between C standards, compilers and systems, but casting away `const` and modifying the value should be undefined behavior. Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574542/is-it-ub-to-cast-away-const-and-read-value). Some systems might just segfault, others will probably work if you try to hack your way around `const` with casting. So this will be difficult.

If you want to make this pointer-shenanigans at least somewhat difficult, how about creating some API. You could try to pass a function, that does the reading on a memory location you defined before you call `foo`. Then again, you could just copy and afterwards pass it.

Answer (score 2):

C declaration syntax, especially with respect to pointers, is too rich for such a simple macro to be possible.

As you have discovered, it doesn't work for pointers to arrays, pointers to functions, and it won't work for pointers to pointers either.

If you're passing a pointer to an array and you want to make sure individual array elements are const, you'll have to do it the hard way:

```
void foo( const T (*arr)[N] ); // or T const (*arr)[N]
```